# Counting table results: A PHP switch case that uses a radio button value

Tags: php, switch-statement

I edited the post for a better understanding. This is my first project as a student-trainee. It is an equipment monitoring system that keeps a record of computer equipment. This is part of code in a page that contains a filtering option and a table that displays a list of computer equipment. The filtering option contains several radio buttons that belongs to two categories which are State and Condition. Please see the components of the two categories at the end of the post. The components are the radio button values.

The page reloads when another radio button is clicked similar to Facebook search. I wanted **to count the number of equipment per Condition and State to be displayed beside the radio button label**. BUT, the state radio buttons affect the counting of equipment. For example, New EQ is the type of equipment that was just entered into the inventory. When the New EQ button is checked and Available/Unassigned button is also checked, the table result will be filtered that will display results that contain equipment with a state that is New and a condition that is Available/Unassigned. The table result will be counted and will be outputted beside the radio button label which tells the user how many equipment are **"New"** and **"Available/Unassigned"**. When another state radio button is clicked, such as Old EQ button, The displayed quantity of the Available/Unassigned equipment beside the label will change depending on the number of rows returned because the user changed the request to output equipment that is **"Old" and "Available/Unassigned"**. BTW the state and condition are columns in the same table. This will happen to all the radio buttons. If the user clicks another radio button under the Condition category, such as the **Assigned EQ** button, the quantity of the Available/Unassigned displayed beside the label will change to 0 or zero because the user requested that the table result should display equipment that are **New and Assigned**, the equipment that is Available/Unassigned was not requested. If the user clicks **"All condition"** button, it will count the table rows that contain **ALL** the conditions which also has a data on its row a **New** state. The filtering process to display table results is already functioning. I am now working on outputting the quantities beside the radio button labels.
[image]
[image]

```php
<?php

switch($state AND $condition){
    case $state=="allstate" AND $condition=="allcondition":
        $sql3="SELECT *FROM eq_inv WHERE eq_condition='Available/Unassigned'";
        break;

    case $state=="new" AND $condition=="allcondition":
        $sql3="SELECT *FROM eq_inv WHERE eq_condition='Available/Unassigned' AND eq_state='new'";
        break;

    case $state=="old" AND $condition=="allcondition":
        $sql3="SELECT *FROM eq_inv WHERE eq_condition='Available/Unassigned' AND eq_state='old'";
        break;

    case $state=="Unknown state" AND $condition=="allcondition":
        $sql3="SELECT *FROM eq_inv WHERE eq_condition='Available/Unassigned' AND eq_state='Unknown state'";
        break;

    case $state=="Unknown state" AND $condition=="Available/Unassigned":
        $sql3="SELECT *FROM eq_inv WHERE eq_condition='Available/Unassigned' AND eq_state='Unknown state'";
        break;
}
         //Code above is incomplete
$result3=mysqli_query($conn,$sql3);
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result3);
echo "<label style='color:red;'><strong>".$count."</strong></label>";

?>
```

Categories:

**State:** All state,new,old,unknown state

**Condition:** All condition,available/unassigned,repair,missing parts, missing eq, defective, refurbished,unknown condition

Comment: You don't need the switch cases. You can just substitute the `eq_condition` and `eq_state` with the values. Use escaped values / prepared statements to avoid SQL Injection.

Comment: Don't you have some logic rule to build your query ? If you have more than 32 different case to build a query with 2 params, you have some logic problem about how you do it I think

Comment: as per your requirement, I don't think that there is any need of switch case. I may be wrong, but as per your code above, IF ELSE is enough.

Comment: I edited the post because it was incomplete, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`switch($state AND $condition)` will evaluate to true or false depending of the values `$state` and `$condition`.

So the only useful cases then are

- `case true`
- `case false`
- `case default`

In your case you should use if / else construct.

## Update

Because asked in the comments how to write the conditions anyway in a switch construct see the nested code here:

```php
switch ($state)
{
    case "allstate":
        if ($condition == "allcondition")
            $sql3 = "SELECT *FROM eq_inv WHERE eq_condition='Available/Unassigned'";
        break;

    case "new":
        if ($condition == "allcondition")
            $sql3 = "SELECT *FROM eq_inv WHERE eq_condition='Available/Unassigned' AND eq_state='new'";
        break;

    case "old":
        if ($condition == "allcondition")
            $sql3 = "SELECT *FROM eq_inv WHERE eq_condition='Available/Unassigned' AND eq_state='old'";
        break;

    case "Unknown state":
        switch ($condition)
        {
            case "Available/Unassigned":
            case "allcondition":
                $sql3 = "SELECT *FROM eq_inv WHERE eq_condition='Available/Unassigned' AND eq_state='Unknown state'";
                break;

        }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to make switch($state AND $condition) a true case?

Comment: Looking at your code it would be always true, because $state and $condition are **not** empty strings. True AND True = True.

Comment: I learned that Inserting multiple OR in a case statement in the code I posted is impossible. How can I put multiple conditions in a case statement to shorten the code?

Comment: @jonaspalmiano You also can nest switch statements. Then you can create the **or** condition depending on the first case. See my answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<?php
$sql3="SELECT *FROM eq_inv WHERE eq_condition='Available/Unassigned'";

if(in_array($state, ['new', 'old', 'Unknown state']) && in_array($condition, ['allcondition', 'Available/Unassigned'])) {
  $sql3 .=" AND eq_state='".$state."'";
}

$result3=mysqli_query($conn,$sql3);
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result3);
echo "<label style='color:red;'><strong>".$count."</strong></label>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing with you guys the working code:

```
<label style="font-size:20px;"><strong>Filter Result:</strong></label>
<?php
$state=$_SESSION['state'];
$condition=$_SESSION['condition'];
echo "<label style='color:red;'>"." "."State:"." ".$state." "."-"." 
"."Condition:"." ".$condition."</label>";
?>
<br>
<div class="filters">
<?php
}
?>
<script>
  function handleRadio(data){
   window.location="sessionstate.php?state="+data.value;
  }
  function handleRadiocond(data2){
    window.location="sessioncondition.php?condition="+data2.value;
  }
  </script>
```

The rest of the code is [here](https://pastebin.com/3BrjaSSk).